# What is the recommended way of adding additional data to TypeORM entity result when using QueryBuilder?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Given two tables `products` and `promotions`:

```
| products  |
| --------- |
| id        |
| code      |

| promotions |
| ---------- |
| id         |
| matcher    |
| value      |
```

And a rule, that each `product` can have **N** promotions based on whether given promotion **starts** with a given `matcher`:

**Products data**

```
| id | code |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | ABC  |
| 2  | ABZ  |
```

**Promotions data**

```
| id | matcher | value |
| -- | ------- | ----- |
| 1  | A       | 10    | <- Matches ABC and ABZ
| 2  | AB      | 20    | <- Matches ABC and ABZ
| 3  | ABC     | 30    | <- Matches ABC
| 4  | ABZ     | 40    | <- Matches ABZ
```

I want to return each product and the number of promotions it matches:

```
[
  { id: 1, code: 'ABC', promotions_count: 3 },
  { id: 2, code: 'ABZ', promotions_count: 3 },
]
```

Here's my current solution:

```
return this.productsRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('products', 'product')
  .select('product.*')
  .addSelect('count(promotions.id)', 'promotions_count')
  .leftJoin('promotions', 'promotion', 'start_with(product.code, promotion.matcher)')
  .groupBy('product.id')
  .getRawMany()
```

While this works I don't like the idea of using `getRawMany` method instead of letting TypeORM return the entity + additional data.

I checked `getRawAndEntities` but it doesn't seem to be returning the data am I after as well.

*What is the recommended way of adding additional data to TypeORM entity result when using QueryBuilder?*